# jQuery - cannot simulate click

Tags: jquery, events, coffeescript, jasmine

I am trying to write Jasmine tests for various behaviours. One of them being when user clicks on a header link, which brings up a popup.

This is the test code

```
describe "Popup", ->
  it "should open notifications when clicked", ->
    ($ '.popup#notifications').click()

    expect(($ '.popup-box')).toHaveClass 'opened'
```

This is the event

```
Eventor.register
  name : 'popup'
  handler : Stp.Helper.triggers() //returns click mousedown
  element : '.popup'
  cb : (e) =>
    e.preventDefault()
    @popup null, ($ e.currentTarget)
```

This is the HTML

```
<a class="icon popup" id="notifications" href="http://localhost:8000/frontend/my-account/notifications">
  <i id="notification-mark" class="" style="opacity: 0; display: none;"></i>
  <span class="sprite notifications"></span>
</a>
```

The test fails. The click event is not triggered at all. I tried changing the element to

```
($ '.popup#notifications')[0].click()
```

but that completely ignores the preventDefault and instead redirects to the page.

Comment: $( '.popup#notifications')[0].click()

Comment: Please can you clarify your language? (CoffeeScript?) It seems to me this is misleading people.

Comment: I see no node with ```popup-box``` classname in your HTML, and also it's unclear why should it also have ```opened``` classname.

Comment: @undeletable Popup-box is the actual modal window.  The method "@popup" adds the class opened to the box.

Comment: @Foxhoundn would be great if you post this all as code, otherwise I'm not sure they're OK.

Comment: Since it's coffeeScript, `($ '.popup#notifications').click()` is actually valid, because parenthesis are optional. `$ '#popup'` compiles to `$('#popup')`.   `($ '.popup#notifications').click()` will compile to `($('.popup#notifications')).click()`  which is equivalent to `$('.popup#notifications').click()`.